# Do WCF Client machine MUST needs to have all DLLs WCF service has referenced to?

Tags: c#, wcf

**Edit**

Please add a reference to your answer, so I could convince my system admin. Thanks

**Scenario**

I have a WCF web services, which has reference to few third party dlls, e.g. Microsoft.SharePoint, now when I try to call web services from client machine using this code, it says Microsoft.SharePoint not found.

Problem does goes away when I add Microsoft.SharePoint to client machine's GAC, but I am failed to explain it to our System Admin as why we need to add Microsoft.SharePoint dll to client WCF machine. **Can someone explain why we must need to add WCF service's referenced dlls to client machine..**

BTW, I deployed WCF service by making Microsoft.SharePoint copy local but not much changes.

Here is the error, I get when I remove dll from GAC,

> Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   SourceCode.Workflow.Runtime.Extenders.CodeExtender.OnExecute(Object
>   context, XmlElement data, ResolverManager resolverManager)    at
>   SourceCode.Workflow.Runtime.Extenders.ResolverExtenderBase.Execute(Object
>   context, String data)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   SourceCode.Workflow.Runtime.IK2Extender.Execute(Object context, String
>   data)    at SourceCode.KO.ProcessInstance.ExecuteExtender(Guid , State
>   , ContextType , Object , Int32 , String , Guid )An exception was
>   thrown during execution of a K2 workflow. This process instance is now
>   in an error state. The details of the exception are listed below.

**Code**

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = GetNetWorkCredentials();
   BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
   binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
   binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = creds.httpClientCredentialType;
   ChannelFactory<Portal.WebServices.Internal.IPort> factory = new ChannelFactory<Portal.WebServices.Internal.IPort>(binding);
   factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
   factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = creds.UserName;
   factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = creds.Password;
   Portal.WebServices.Internal.IPort proxy = factory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(siteURL + "/_vti_bin/portal/Port.svc"));
   Portal.WebServices.Internal.FewObject[] invoices = proxy.GetInvoices(IDs);
```

Comment: Can you show us the interface of `Portal.WebServices.Internal.IPort`. If it's large, just show us the `GetInvoices` method.

Comment: It's interesting that it works when **Microsoft.SharePoint.dll** is placed in the GAC but not on the file system - makes me think it is depending on certain security aspects (like `CAS`) available to GAC'd .NET assemblies or that it has dependencies on other files in the GAC.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd thanks you pointed me to the right direction otherwise it took me another day to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add Dlls you add to a WCF service to a client server, but only when you add an object to it's interface.

One of workmate added an OperationContract as below,

```
[OperationContract]
    void AddEventReceiver(string siteUrl, string listName, string assemblyName, string className, SPEventReceiverType receiverType);
```

WCF service was failing because it couldn't compile referenced object in the interface, in my case "SPEventReceiverType".

So make sure you add object references to client machines if they are not generic types.